# Configure Kubectl to connect to a local network Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, docker-desktop

I'm trying to connect to a kubernetes cluster running on my Windows PC from my Mac. This is so I can continue to develop from my Mac but run everything on a machine with more resources. I know that to do this I need to change the kubectl context on my Mac to point towards my Windows PC but don't know how to manually do this.

When I've connected to a cluster before on AKS, I would use `az aks get-credentials` and this would correctly an entry to .kube/config and change the context to it. I'm basically trying to do this but on a local network.

I've tried to add an entry into kubeconfig but get `The connection to the server 192.168.1.XXX:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`. I've also checked my antivirus on the Windows computer and no requests are getting blocked.

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: {CERT}
    server: https://192.168.1.XXX:6443
  name: windows-docker-desktop
current-context: windows-docker-desktop
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: windows-docker-desktop
  user:
    client-certificate-data: {CERT}
    client-key-data: {KEY}
```

I've also tried using `kubectl --insecure-skip-tls-verify --context=windows-docker-desktop get pods` which results in the same error: `The connection to the server 192.168.1.XXX:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`.

Many thanks.

Comment: Is the port blocked by windows firewall? Maybe you need to add a rule to allow incoming traffic on port 6443.

Comment: @Garuno Thanks for the reply. I've just checked, and that port isn't being blocked by Windows Firewall or by my Antivirus, which manages it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your MAC try if the port is open: Like nc -zv 192.168.yourwindowsIp 6443. If it doest respond Open, you have a network problem.
Try this.

```
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: https://192.168.1.XXX:6443
    name: windows-docker-desktop
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
```

directly in the configfile

the set-context you dont need to specify as you have only one.
To be sure it is not your firewall, disable it just for a very short period, only to test the conection.

Last thing: Seems you are using Kubernetes in Docker-Desktop. If not and you have a local cluster with more than 1 node, you need to install a network fabric in your cluster like Flannel or Calico.
https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/about/about-calico
https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It wasn't accessible on 6443, but I found out that I had to run `kubectl proxy --port=6443 --address=192.168.1.XXX --accept-hosts='^.*'` on it, which makes it available. I don't know if this is the best way to do this, I'm guessing not, but it works. I also had to change the server in kubeconfig to use `http` instead of `https` as I was getting a `server gave http response to https client` error. And now everything works as I wanted. Thank you for the help.